# Why is the mariadb sequence reset to next_not_cached_value after restarting the server?

Tags: sql-server, caching, mariadb, sequence, restart

I created a sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE = 20 CACHE = 10 CYCLE;
```

increased sequence.

```
select nextval(my_seq) from dual; // 1
```

Next_not_cached_value became 11.

Increased the sequence again.

```
select nextval(my_seq) from dual; // 2
```

The server was restarted.

Increased the sequence again.

```
select nextval(my_seq) from dual; // 11
```

Why doesn't sequence three?

How should I set it to obtain a sequence of 3?

I look forward to a clear answer.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't restart SQL Server cleanly. As per [CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) _"When created with the CACHE option, an unexpected shutdown (such as a power failure) may result in the loss of sequence numbers remaining in the cache."_ There's also a detailed explanation in Cache Management that elaborates on the behavior.

Comment: 그럼 캐시가 손살되어 next_not_cached 값인 11로 되었는 것인가요?

Comment: The purpose of the `CACHE` is to reduce the amount of disk I/O by keeping a set of values only in memory. When you created the sequence the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 were pre-allocated in the memory cache. The two calls to `nextval()` retrieved the values 1 and 2, meaning that the values 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 were still in the memory cache. If you had shut down SQL Server cleanly then it would have recorded on disk that 3 was the next value to return from `nextval()`.

Comment: Please read [CREATE SEQUENCE # Cache Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql#cache-management) for more information on cache behavior, especially which values get persisted on disk and when.